# How do I remove newly ignored files from Kiln?

Tags: mercurial, kiln

I was wondering why my push was taking so long to Kiln, but by the time I realized that I was uploading unnecessary build artifacts, it was too late. The push was complete. I created an ignore file on my local repository and used "hg purge."  I committed and pushed it to Kiln again, but the ignored files are still there.  How do I remove them permanently including all histories so that I don't have this gigantic repo on Kiln?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I had this issue, I would remove whole repository from Kiln(if you have perm to it), and clone it newly there from local, in case that you have whole repository localy. But I dont know Kiln much, so there may be some restrictions.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it looks like it's the only way to solve the problem.  If a better answer comes along, it may change.